# Perl, GhostScript & STDIN, STDOUT

Tags: perl, stdout, stdin, ghostscript

How can I feed  ghostscript with file from the variable and post the result back to variable without writing to HDD intermediate variants.

maybe ghost is to be called by this line:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%stdout -
```

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=ghostscript&mode=all

Comment: all modules in CPAN don't output to variable, and writing to HDD.

Comment: see the Perl documentation for the "open" function, it explains how to read the output of a command as if it was a file

Comment: tried to use open and open2 functions, did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
use GSAPI qw();
use IO::CaptureOutput qw(capture);

my $pdf;
capture {
    my $handle = GSAPI::new_instance;
    GSAPI::init_with_args($handle, 'TITAN', qw(-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=-));
    GSAPI::run_string($handle, 'newpath 100 200 moveto 200 250 lineto 100 300 lineto closepath gsave 0.5 setgray fill grestore 4 setlinewidth 0.75 setgray stroke showpage');
    GSAPI::exit($handle);
} \$pdf;
```

Comment: There's a patch in the bugtracker.

Comment: I don't believe you. When you say ["it doesn't work"](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html), you are withholding crucial information.

Comment: In this case are you specifying `-` as input file or simply not specifying the input file?  I'm trying to do the same thing (no HDD access at all) in C and keep getting "Unable to open the initial device, quitting.".

Comment: ebyrob, you better [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your C problem. Hint: look at [GSAPI.xs](https://metacpan.org/source/OESI/GSAPI-0.5/GSAPI.xs#L531), the Perl function `run_string` wraps the GSAPI call `gsapi_run_string_with_length`.